# Counter issue ( C Program)

Tags: c

I only want my count_float to reset back to 0 when **Alarm_Status.bits.b3** is not set and when **leakDetected=0**. However it never seems to reset for some reason. When alarm goes off I put leakDetected to 1 so the counter cant be reset. But if alarm goes off for 2 seconds and is disabled again it holds this count of 2. It should reset to 0.

```
{   
    int count_float     
    int fixedCount = 50;
    short  leakDetected=0;
    BS(TRISB,7);    // Bund sw port=input.
    DelayMs(2); // will rise is bund SW open
    if(RB7){                                
        if(Control.bits.BUND_ENABLE){       // if bund alarm enabled
            if(Alarm_Status.bits.b3){   // if  already set
                count_float +=10;       //count increased by 10
                if(count_float == fixedCount) { 
                    leakDetected=1;
                    DU_Reason.bits.EmergencyDialIn=1;// alarm!
                }
            }
            if((!Alarm_Status.bits.b3)&&(!leakDetected)){
                count_float=0;
            }                           
        }   
    } else {
        Alarm_Status.bits.b3=1;     // Bund Sw Closed
        BC(TRISB,7);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just as per the same _essence_ of your question, the reply is you need to have a `;` after `int count_float`.

Comment: Sorry it didn't copy over for some reason

Comment: where is leakDetected set to zero?

Comment: Is this the exact code you are using? nothing missing?

Comment: I put full code in know.

Comment: leakDetected is set to zero at beginning of code

Comment: @mohit-jain I initialized count_float = 0 but still didn't work

Comment: `count_float` and `leakDetected` are both local to the block of code you've posted.  Any changes you make to other variables with the same names in other code that is not reproduced here will have no effect on the variables in this block.

Comment: Is your code supposed to loop at any point? Or is it a one-time check? If so, leakDetected will never reach 50 (at most 10).

Comment: This is in a function that loops every second

Comment: @AutoCad1990 Did you try making `count_float` static?

Comment: Yes still same issue, it wont reset back to 0

Answer (score 3):

You are using `count_float` uninitialized. Accessing a variable without initializing it leads to undefined behavior.

To fix it, simply initialize as:

```
int count_float = 0;
```

---

About your updated question, you initialize `count_float` everytime you come to this loop. If you want it to maintain the previous count(as it is looping every second), please make it `static` as shown below.

```
static int count_float = 0;  /* '= 0' is optional but recommended */
```